# Get the length of one side of this rectangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

[image]

X and Y are areas. The question mark refers to the shorter side of the rectangle.

I tried solving it and got 6.75 as an answer but was told it was wrong.

Let z be the short side:

$17+x+18=7z$

$x+18+y=8z$

$18+y+19=9z$

And I got $z=6.75$

Anything wrong with my systems of equations?

Comment: Mikko, your result is right. Why was it rejected as wrong?

Comment: @Mikko Why did you unaccept my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Let the short side have length $h$. Our equations are $$17+18+x=35+x=7h$$$$18+19+y=37+y=9h$$$$18+x+y=8h$$

If we subtract the third equation from the sum of the other two, we get $$54=8h$$Which implies $h=\color{red}{6.75}$.